# Does the built-in http server implement non-blocking I/O?

Tags: nonblocking, perfect

This is a first server-side swift framework available now. I am interested to use it for high traffic mobile app server.

Does this swift based framework implement the non-blocking I/O http server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the internal networking in Perfect is all non-blocking. This is the case if you are doing raw TCP comms., using the built-in HTTP server or the FastCGI server. Check out the NetTCP and NetNamedPipe classes. They take callbacks when you connect, accept, read or write data. All of the relevant functions take a timeout parameter as well. You can optionally accept custom server connections in a blocking loop.

The individual web handlers are non-blocking as well in that you call a callback to tell the system that you are done with the request. The system will complete the current request and await others utilizing keep-alive.